# Studio Controls v2.2.1-0 does not execute in Ubuntu Studio 20.04.3

Tags: sound, ubuntu-studio, jack

For the past few weeks Studio Controls v2.2.1-0 has failed to execute in Ubuntu Studio 20.04.3. The backports ppa is enabled. Jack appears not to be running. I still have sound (from Pulse Audio?) but Jack does not appear as an option in Audacity. Nor does it appear in the systray Audio Mixer. Any suggestions for troubleshooting this appreciated.

```
 $ apt show studio-controls
Package: studio-controls
Version: 2.2.1-0ubuntu1~ubuntu20.04.1~ppa1
Priority: optional
Section: admin
Maintainer: Erich Eickmeyer
Original-Maintainer: Len Ovens
Installed-Size: 461 kB
Depends: a2jmidid, jackd2, pulseaudio-module-jack, python3-dbus, python3-gi, python3, python3-jack-client, zita-ajbridge, qasmixer, pavucontrol, python3-alsaaudio, init-system-helpers (>= 1.52)
Recommends: qmidinet, zita-njbridge
Suggests: carla
Conflicts: cadence, studio-controls (<= 2.0.9-0ubuntu1), ubuntustudio-controls (<< 1.13)
Replaces: studio-controls (<= 2.0.9-0ubuntu1), ubuntustudio-controls (<< 1.13)
Download-Size: 96.1 kB
APT-Manual-Installed: yes
APT-Sources: http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntustudio-ppa/backports/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
Description: Studio Controls - Jack Audio Configuration Tool
Studio Controls is a small application that enables/disables realtime
privilege for users and controls jackdbus. It allows Jackdbus to be run from
session start. It also will detect USB audio devices getting plugged in after
session start and optionally connect them to jackdbus as a client or switch
them in as jackdbus master.
```

The following may also be of interest:

```
studio-controls
install path: /usr
Config file: /home/user/.config/autojack/autojack.json
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/studio-controls", line 1836, in <module>
    us = StudioControls()
  File "/usr/bin/studio-controls", line 602, in __init__
    self.refresh_dropdowns()
  File "/usr/bin/studio-controls", line 888, in refresh_dropdowns
    desc_base = f"{this_dev} {dev_db['id']} {dev_db['bus']} {dev_db['raw']},{this_sub},0"
KeyError: 'id'
```

A system update has just updated Studio Controls to v2.2.3-0 but it has not solved the above problem. Studio Controls still fails to launch/execute.

```
$ studio-controls
install path: /usr
Config file: /home/user/.config/autojack/autojack.json
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/studio-controls", line 1836, in <module>
    us = StudioControls()
  File "/usr/bin/studio-controls", line 602, in __init__
    self.refresh_dropdowns()
  File "/usr/bin/studio-controls", line 888, in refresh_dropdowns
    desc_base = f"{this_dev} {dev_db['id']} {dev_db['bus']} {dev_db['raw']},{this_sub},0"
KeyError: 'id'
```

If I boot a live CD of Ubuntu Studio 20.0.4, Studio Controls launches fine.

Comment: If you still have this problem, try to fully update your system as stated [here](https://ubuntustudio.org/2020/07/major-backports-update/) with `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt full-upgrade`.